# Вывод данных из бд Realm в ListView

Tags: android, realm, realm-android

Делаю подобие органайзера. В Realm как и в Android новичок. Пытаюсь вывести данные из бд в Список, но не знаю как это правильно сделать. Адаптер брал [тут](https://metanit.com/java/android/5.6.php) и [тут](https://metanit.com/java/android/5.8.php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сущность Records:

```
public class Services extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Cущность Services:

```
public class Services extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Records> records = new ArrayList();
    ListView List;
    TextView lTime, lServ;

    Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Realm.init(this);
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //lTime=findViewById(R.id.lTime);
        //lServ=findViewById(R.id.lServ);

        // начальная инициализация списка
        setInitialData();
        // получаем элемент ListView
        List = findViewById(R.id.list);
        // создаем адаптер
        Adapter stateAdapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.list_item, records);
        // устанавливаем адаптер
        List.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
        // слушатель выбора в списке
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // получаем выбранный пункт
                Records selectedRecord = (Records) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Был выбран пункт " + selectedRecord.getServices().get(0).getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        List.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }
    private void setInitialData(){

        realm.beginTransaction();
        Records records = realm.createObject(Records.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Services services = realm.createObject(Services.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
       // records.setTime(time.getText().toString());
        //services.setName(serv.getText().toString());
        records.add(new Records (records.getTime(), records.getServices().get(0).getName()));
        realm.commitTransaction();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Запис успішно додано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        realm.close();


        records.add(new Records ("Чили", "Сантьяго"));
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Records> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private List<Records> records;

    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Records> records) {
        super(context, resource, records);
        this.records = records;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Records record = records.get(position);

        // viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(state.getFlagResource());
        viewHolder.timeView.setText(record.getTime());
        viewHolder.servView.setText(record.getServices().get(0).getName());

        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        // final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView servView, timeView;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            // imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lTime);
            servView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lServ);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается перед выводом нужно создать запрос. В итоге setInitialData() выглядит так:

```
private void setInitialData(){

        realm.beginTransaction();
        RealmResults<Records> results = realm.where(Records.class).findAll();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.list_item, results);
        ListV.setAdapter(adapter);
        realm.close();
    }
```